# Nested ternary condition inside Typescript type extends

Tags: typescript, interface, extends

I'm transitioning from JavaScript development to an employer that enforces TypeScript typing. I created an `Interface` for a model that contains a typical `.on(event, handler)`.

My colleague came up with some code that I think understand, but it uses this nested ternary statement that makes it confusing to read.

```
interface Model {
    ...
    on<T extends "added" | "failed" | "initialized" | "changed" | "removed"> (
        event: T,
        handler: T extends "changed" | "removed"
                 ? (T extends "changed"
                     ? (model: Model, entity: Entity, data: object) => void
                     : (model: Model, id: string) => void)
                 : (model: Model, entity: Entity) => void,
        context?: object
    ): void
}
```

It seems like a way to have different signatures for the `handler` argument based on which `event` was passed in.

It seems to be working, but I'm wondering if there is a different pattern for writing this such that it is a bit easier to read and understand.

Comment: Is there another Stack Exchange network site that would be a more appropriate place to ask this question?

Comment: I would probably index into a mapping interface instead of using nested conditionals here; if nobody gets here before I get to a real computer I will post an answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'd consider using a mapping interface and indexing into it, since the operation "map a string literal to a particular type" is naturally given to you in TypeScript by object types.  While you *can* use conditional types to do this, it does tend to be harder to read and maintain.

As a first step to refactoring, I'd do something like this:

```
// use a mapping from event name to event handler type
interface EventHandlerMap {
  added: (model: Model, entity: Entity) => void;
  failed: (model: Model, entity: Entity) => void;
  initialized: (model: Model, entity: Entity) => void;
  changed: (model: Model, entity: Entity, data: object) => void;
  removed: (model: Model, id: string) => void;
}

interface Model {
  on<T extends keyof EventHandlerMap>(
    event: T,
    handler: EventHandlerMap[T], // index into the mapping
    context?: object
  ): void;
}
```

You can convince yourself that it acts the same way (or use the link to the code at the end to see).  The `EventHandlerMap` interface is just a helper that you don't actually assign to any objects.  But it describes the mapping from `Model.on()`'s `event` parameter of type `T` to the `handler` parameter. And we use [lookup types](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/wiki/What's-new-in-TypeScript#keyof-and-lookup-types) to pull out the `handler` type as `EventHandlerMap[T]`.

It might be possible to further refactor this... for example, all of those are functions returning `void` and the first parameter is `Model`; perhaps you could make `EventHandlerMap` only keep track of what is different among the different event and then use a more complex type manipulation, but that might be more trouble than it's worth.

Okay, hope that helps; good luck!

[Link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgKLmGAnsg3gKGWQgC5kBnMKUAcwG5kB6R5AeymQHcALOSAN2j4Avvnwg4AWwjkADohQAFKBH55CyUJFgLkAWVYATCABt1RIqxAAeACrEAHpBCHyyAERxDxw++QAfD3hgEwhfAI9QTGA4E2AALzC-QPcEXhAaJIj3FUlWQV8APgAKDQtiQXAyWwAaMot0w1CoasdnVw80uAyslNz8pPrygH5kYvsIJwgXN1T0zN8h8otR4rzjEzIDDZriDGwydDBMLF3DPjgyVgAjACsIBDAASmQAXkLkflZgQyXl5DIayMpi2wJMux+ZEo1AyL3en2+hiefwBY3WIP0YN202OBzQ+ywcI+Xx+dX+CCskCcwyudweYHqTzIJMMdA0og0xgQJjgKmQFJAlGQ6M2mI2bKIIoAdFZip5vEldkCdntcYS3h8AAxPCXCsEykBy4KhXxKkXYglE5Da3XS2XuKLHWIJRVorGqk5Wm0aO2GubdBbuM3unEnM4XL06n36+39ApBt0qn6RtkciTSOS6ABykzA5iYLAAruQUHBhXBZLJaMgYFBWJIKjjkOmUGBWI3wMhGs1kNhZBANFpoPAkGhKmAABLdJrQPQV-NELw+QEi0Eq0N4o6ejUIn66ojGsIrsFr0wWtWHS07ln7zQgaLOxKGY8bU-gj2bq-wm-1Lo9Z+Jhi2xnh+WCXmq4ZgJcbB0o8Vo-uUcZHoBorAe+kIUFQtDwYiuockQQ46KOaELmwNgTFMMzIAA1hAWCsDAY44lOLjNHOsglEsqg4tUZLLN20CHOOLEzlA7EANq2AAurszB3sYDh3m2vbcCgkgVlWGRLAKVJgDSMH3I8jLMrh7JiEQXI8nyApCquYqmLaMZ+kurrKiBG7qvC3qSk5RpwCErnmqBKbRhsBpyo6MRxE+CZue+HkhT5YX2n+gbBuuBKQXAiV6slfpIaaKEQkiO7eqIQA)

Comment: Appreciate the thoughtful response. I think you're approach with the mapper interface and the use of `keyof` to link the `event` and `handler` methods makes sense to me. I like that it offers flexibility to add new mappings as needed in a style familiar to the rest of the code. I agree that further refactoring to reduce some redundancy might be overkill, whereas this feels more natural to other overload languages. Thank you for your time and feedback.